# Need to make awk suppress the output to stdout

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I wanted to use `awk` for a solution of mine to parse records row-wise (looping upto max elements (upto `NF`)) and then store some of the fields in a `bash` variable. I was able to get the records I need, but couldn't avoid `awk` printing
its own output to `stdout`.

This is the example I adopted.

```
newvar=$(echo "Hello, this is a sentence with a few words." | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }'
```

I wanted to store the words `Hello, this is a sentence` in the bash variable `newvar`. Though there are more efficient ways to do this, for the moment consider the way to do with `awk` only.

This is storing the output as the one below in the variable

```
Hello, this is a sentence with a few words. Hello, this is a sentence
```

I tried suppressing the `stdout` to the `null` by doing `1>&-` as,

```
$ newvar=$(echo "Hello, this is a sentence with a few words." | awk '{ s = ""; for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }'  1>&- )
```

Got an ugly error saying,

> awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: error writing standard output (Bad file descriptor)

Haven't been able to find a decent answer here nor anywhere on how to do this.  Is this even possible with `awk`? Duplication of the exact post if found is appreciated too!

Comment: Why not correct the error rather than suppress the the error message?

Comment: Seems to work fine to me provided you add the closing parenthesis at the end of the line and I imagine you meant to loop between 1 and 5 as 0 holds _all_ the words on the matched line.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Not really sure what you meant!

Comment: @patthoyts:Silly me! should have avoided `$0` Appreciate your time

Comment: @Inian Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you wanted to suppress the error message. I see now that I was wrong.

Comment: @to_whoever_downvoted:  Please provide the information I failed to provide in this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you are looping from 0 to 5. This means that you are storing `$0` in the variable `s` and, as you know, `$0` contains the full record. This means you are storing the full record followed by the 5 first fields.

So just loop from 1 to 5:

```
$ awk '{s = ""; for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) s = s $i " "; print s }' <<< "Hello, this is a sentence with a few words."
Hello, this is a sentence
```

Note by the way that it is not necessary to set `s` as `""` in the beginning: any variable does get set when you start using it. Although you may be using this because you have multiple lines, so that you need to reset its value after every record.

This being said, if you just want to print the first 5 words, use `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f-5 <<< "Hello, this is a sentence with a few words."Hello, this is a sentence
```

Comment: That was something really basic! Accepting it! no more efficient answers could be applicable!